# Error adding Firebase SDK to app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in a app, following [google's guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). I've added the `google-services.json` to the `app` folder and was trying to add the SDK.

Following the guide, I wrote in the `build.gradle (Project)`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
                }
}
```

And on `build.gradle(Module: mobile)`:

```
dependencies
{
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    (...)
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is when the problem starts. After a Grade sync, an error message appears saying: `Error:(34, 0) Version: 7.3.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.`

I try to update by changing `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'` and again new errors, errors that I've no idea how to solve...:

```
Error:orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode|smallestScreenSize) from AndroidManifest.xml:79:4-113

Error:orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize).

Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity@configChanges value=(keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode|smallestScreenSize) from AndroidManifest.xml:79:4-113
    is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-122 value=(keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:77:3-79:116 to override.
```

Sorry for the long. Android newbie here. Thanks for all the future help!

Edit: `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.www.appname"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- versionCode, versionName, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion properties are set via Gradle script -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" /> <!-- allows the API to access Google web-based services -->

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />


    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:configChanges">


        <activity
            android:name="com.www.appname.activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.www.appname.activity.DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_detail"
            android:launchMode="standard" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.www.appname.activity.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_map"
            android:launchMode="standard" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode|smallestScreenSize" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.www.appname.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider"
            android:authorities="ccom.www.appname.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider"
            android:exported="false" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_tracker" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/maps_api_key" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

sync gradle file, clean and rebuild the project.

and add   `'tools:replace="android:configChanges"'` into  tag inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

**EDIT**

remove:

`tools:replace="android:icon" tools:replace="android:configChanges"`

add:

`tools:replace="android:icon, android:configChanges"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if I'm placing tools:replace="android:configChanges on the right place. I added it to:

 `<application
  android:name=".CityGuideApplication"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.CityGuide.Blue"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  tools:replace="android:icon"
  tools:replace="android:configChanges">`

Comment: @Harkadya , seems ok. if you can, post your full manifest file in  the question to be sure.

Comment: But new errors appear:
'Error:Attribute "replace" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/tools" was already specified for element "application".'

'Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
> Exception while parsing the supplied manifest file´

Comment: @Harkadya `tools:replace="android:icon, android:configChanges"`

Comment: @Harkadya and remove `tools:replace="android:icon" tools:replace="android:configChanges"`

Comment: I don't understand sorry. should I remove `tools:replace="android:icon, android:configChanges">`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. 

`Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

I'll look around. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Harkadya , as I understood, I've merged two `replace` tags togather. Try to clean and rebuild project after that.

Comment: @Harkadya  and post your crahs log  here  after clear+rebuild

Answer (score 0):

1. **Remove** `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`

That library includes EVERY Google library for android in a single library.

You Should never use that library and instead you should use only the specific library you actually need, like:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-NAME_OF_THE_LIBRARY'`

2. **Use the same version for libs from** `com.google.android.gms` and `com.google.firebase`

If you use different version for these libraries you risk a lot of conflicts both at compile and run time.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding firebase messaging dependency

```
compile com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1
```

Comment: try with compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'